# Overlapping sliding window over an image using blockproc or im2col?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, dct

I have to apply `dct2` to small windows of my image, preferably by using an overlapping window.

I have found out that there are two functions in Matlab that can make this possible `blockproc` and `im2col`. I am having trouble understanding either and would appreciate some clarification.

`blockproc` can be used to implement my function on a sliding window using the `BorderSize` and `TrimBorder` arguments.

```
B = blockproc(A,[64,64],fun,'BorderSize',[5,5], 'TrimBorder', 'false');
```

I realize that this creates a block of `[64 + 2*5, 64 + 2*5]` and applies the function `@fun` on each block. But since  I cannot go into my function `@fun` in debugging to verify proper operation I cannot be sure this is what I need.
Is my above code correct for what I need? I know that I get a concatenated result in `B` but it should be on a overlapping sliding block. Will this achieve what I need?

The second is `im2col`. `im2col(A,[m n],block_type)` will divide the block into m by n blocks and arrange them in columns, so each column is a block? If so, how is the overlapping controlled? And if each block is a column can I successfully apply the `dct2` function on each column? Because I doubt it will take vectors as input?

Some clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, this is quite a complex question.  I'll try and break this up into separate parts and will answer each question separately.

## Question #1

> `blockproc` can be used to implement my function on a sliding window using the `BorderSize` and `TrimBorder` arguments.
>
> `B = blockproc(A,[64,64],fun,'BorderSize',[5,5], 'TrimBorder', 'false');`
>
> I realize that this creates a block of `[64 + 2*5, 64 + 2*5]` and applies the function `@fun` on each block. But since I cannot go into my function `@fun` in debugging to verify proper operation I cannot be sure this is what I need. Is my above code correct for what I need? I know that I get a concatenated result in `B` but it should be on a overlapping sliding block. Will this achieve what I need?

After experimenting around with `blockproc`, this is indeed correct where you can use it to get sliding neighbourhood processing working.  However, you're going to need an additional flag, which is `PadPartialBlocks`.  The purpose of this flag is so that if you are extracting a block where you're at the outer edges of the image and you can't make a block of a specified size, this will zero-pad this partial block so that it conforms to the same size.  Here's a small example to get this working with sliding windows.  Supposing we had a matrix such that:

```
>> A = reshape(1:25,5,5)

A =

     1     6    11    16    21
     2     7    12    17    22
     3     8    13    18    23
     4     9    14    19    24
     5    10    15    20    25
```

Let's say we wanted to take the average of each 3 x 3 overlapping neighbourhood in the matrix above, and zero-padding those elements that go beyond the borders of the matrix.  You would do this with `blockproc`:

```
B = blockproc(A, [1 1], @(x) mean(x.data(:)), 'BorderSize', [1 1], 'TrimBorder', false, 'PadPartialBlocks', true);
```

What's important to note is that the block size, which is 1 x 1 in this case and `BorderSize` which is 1 x 1 as well are set differently than what you'd expect for a 3 x 3 block.  To go into why this is the case, we need some further insight on how `BorderSize` works.  For a given centre of a block, `BorderSize` allows you to capture values / pixels **beyond the dimensions of the originally** sized block.  For those locations that go beyond the borders of the matrix, we would pad these locations as zero by default.  `BorderSize` allows us to capture `2M + 2N` pixels more, where `M` and `N` are the horizontal and vertical border size you want.  This would allow us to capture `M` more pixels both above and below the original block and `N` more pixels to the left and right of the original block.

Therefore, for the value of 1 in `A`, if the block size is 1 x 1, this means that the element consists of only 1, and if our `BorderSize` was 1 x 1.  This means our final block would be:

```
0  0  0
0  1  6
0  2  7
```

Because our block size is 1, the next block would be centred at 6, and we would get a 3 x 3 grid of pixels and so on.  It is also important that `TrimBorder` is set to `false` so that we can keep those pixels that were originally captured upon expansion of the block.  The default is set to `true`.  Finally, `PadPartialBlocks` is `true` to ensure that all blocks are the same size.  When you run the above code, the result we get is:

```
B =

    1.7778    4.3333    7.6667   11.0000    8.4444
    3.0000    7.0000   12.0000   17.0000   13.0000
    3.6667    8.0000   13.0000   18.0000   13.6667
    4.3333    9.0000   14.0000   19.0000   14.3333
    3.1111    6.3333    9.6667   13.0000    9.7778
```

You can verify that we get the same result using [`nlfilter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/nlfilter.html) where we can apply the mean to 3 x 3 sliding neighbourhoods:

```
C = nlfilter(A, [3 3], @(x) mean(x(:)))

C =

    1.7778    4.3333    7.6667   11.0000    8.4444
    3.0000    7.0000   12.0000   17.0000   13.0000
    3.6667    8.0000   13.0000   18.0000   13.6667
    4.3333    9.0000   14.0000   19.0000   14.3333
    3.1111    6.3333    9.6667   13.0000    9.7778
```

As such, if you want to properly use `blockproc` for sliding operations, you need to be careful on how you set the block size and border size respectively.  In this case, the general rule is to always set your block size to be 1 x 1, and allow `BorderSize` to specify the size of each block you want.  Specifically, for a block of size `K x K`, you would set `BorderSize` to be `floor(K/2) x floor(K/2)` respectively.  It would make things easy if `K` was odd.

For example, if you wanted a `5 x 5` mean filtering operation on a sliding window basis, you would set `BorderSize` to `[2 2]`, as `K = 5` and `floor(K/2) = 2`.  Therefore, you would do this:

```
B = blockproc(A, [1 1], @(x) mean(x.data(:)), 'BorderSize', [2 2], 'TrimBorder', false, 'PadPartialBlocks', true)

B =

    2.5200    4.5600    7.2000    6.9600    6.1200
    3.6000    6.4000   10.0000    9.6000    8.4000
    4.8000    8.4000   13.0000   12.4000   10.8000
    4.0800    7.0400   10.8000   10.2400    8.8800
    3.2400    5.5200    8.4000    7.9200    6.8400
```

Replicating this with `nlfilter` with a size of 5 x 5 also gives:

```
C = nlfilter(A, [5 5], @(x) mean(x(:)))

C =

    2.5200    4.5600    7.2000    6.9600    6.1200
    3.6000    6.4000   10.0000    9.6000    8.4000
    4.8000    8.4000   13.0000   12.4000   10.8000
    4.0800    7.0400   10.8000   10.2400    8.8800
    3.2400    5.5200    8.4000    7.9200    6.8400
```

I was doing some timing tests, and it seems that `blockproc` used in this context is faster than `nlfilter`.

## Question #2

> The second is `im2col`. `im2col(A,[m n],block_type)` will divide the block into m by n blocks and arrange them in columns, so each column is a block? If so, how is the overlapping controlled? And if each block is a column can I successfully apply the `dct2` function on each column? Because I doubt it will take vectors as input?

You are correct in that `im2col` transforms each pixel neighbourhood or block into a single column and the concatenation of these columns forms the output matrix.  You can control whether the blocks are overlapping or are distinct by the `block_type` parameter.  Specify `distinct` or `sliding` (which is default) to control this.  You can also control the size of each neighbourhood with `m` and `n`.

However, if it is your goal to apply `dct2` with the output of `im2col`, then you will not get what you desire. Specifically, `dct2` takes the spatial location of each data point within your 2D data into account and is used as part of the transform.  By transforming each pixel neighbourhood into a single column, the 2D spatial relationships that were originally there for each block are now gone.  `dct2` expects 2D spatial data, but you would be specifying 1D data instead.  As such, `im2col` is probably not what you're looking for.  If I understand what you want correctly, you'll want to use `blockproc` instead.

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot @rayryeng for that excellent and detailed explanation. Bounty added and given(when it becomes available) for such a detailed and helpful reply :)

Comment: @FarazKhan - Oh thank you very much for the bounty!  You didn't have to at all!  BTW, this contradicts what I said about not being able to use `blockproc` in a sliding window approach with your previous question... because after I performed some experimentation, you certainly can... you just have to really fool around with the parameters.  This was a very interesting question and I also learned something out of all of this too.  Also, thanks for posing the question!

Comment: After playing with the above code I believe ``blockproc`` produces a output that is not ideal for my classifier. Each block should produce a vector of size ``1x200`` but I am getting a ``1x1600`` vector for smaller blocks. I found this to be work of ``blockproc`` as it concatenates the results of 4 blocks, ``ul_output``, ``ll_output``, ``ur_output``, ``lr_output``, so it divides areas into smaller blocks and then concatenates then together, This will not work on my classifier. As I need output of each block alone. I tried to change internal function settings but failed.

Comment: @FarazKhan - Could you perhaps post another question and talk about what you're doing in more detail?  I may be able to help you and answer your questions.

Comment: Agreed, there was way much that needed to be said for a comment. I'll just start a new question :)

Comment: @rayryeng I posted a question a while ago and found it similar to what you explained. may i ask if I'm doing the same mistake? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57407606/blockproc-error-when-including-bordersize-argument