# MATLAB: Blockproc with overlapping windows but no padding

Tags: matlab, image-processing, sliding-window, windowing

I spent quite some time on understanding and applying the Matlab function `blockproc`.
I also read some posts on stackoverflow on this function, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735848/bordersize-and-trimborder-in-matlab-blockproc-function), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29040688/overlapping-sliding-window-over-an-image-using-blockproc-or-im2col) one, still I can not utilize the function as I want.

Basically, all I want is a *sliding window* on my image, which *overlaps* the windows, but does *not (zero-) pad* the edges of the image.

For example, on a 10x10 image, I'd like to apply a 8x8 window, with an overlap of 2. IF

`img = reshape(1:100,[10,10]);`

then, in Matlab-Notation, I'd like to get the

*desired ranges*:

```
    [1:8,  1:8] [1:8,  3:10]
    [3:10, 1:8] [3:10, 3:10]
```

The command I thought would do the trick is:

```
fun = @(block_struct) mean2(block_struct.data); 
blockproc(img, [4,4], fun, 'BorderSize', [2,2], 'TrimBorder', true)
```

Where, 4+2*2=8 is my windowsize, and the 2 indicates the overlap.
However this does not work.
I tried other combinations of parameters and values, but with no luck.

I would be really glad if someone could help me out! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your problem is that `blockproc` uses "outside" of the image? Why not compute everything and just dump the part you dont like? you have time requirements?