# Blockproc error when including BorderSize argument

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I'm working on the exercise by Matlab on dct https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/discrete-cosine-transform.html

and i ran the following code:

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif'); 
I = im2double(I);
imshow(I)

T = dctmtx(8);
dct = @(block_struct) T * block_struct.data * T';
B = blockproc(I,[8 8],dct,'BorderSize',[4 4],'Trim',false) %modification made here
```

The code was from the link above, but i included the 'BorderSize' criteria to allow for overlapping of the blocks. Upon running the code, i get the error saying:

```
Error using blockprocFunDispatcher
BLOCKPROC encountered an error while evaluating the user-supplied function handle,FUN.

Error in blockprocInMemory
[u1_output fun_nargout] = blockprocFunDispatcher(fun,block_struct,...

Error in blockproc
    result_image = blockprocInMemory(source,fun,options);
```

What could be the issue causing the error message above? If i **remove 'BorderSize',[4 4], 'Trim',false** it works as normal like in the link but am i using it wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

Are you accounting for the fact that with BorderSize specified, your block size will be bigger in your definition of the function dct? Your function will receive a 12x12 block, sounds to me like a size mismatch in the matrix multiplies with T and T'. Do you need to change the definition of T to:

```
T = dctmx(12)
```

?